# Flink Sql deduplication before a TVF

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

We are trying to run a FlinkSQL query that applies some deduplication and then windows and aggregates the result of that deduplication, but running into the following error at query plan time:
`org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: StreamPhysicalWindowAggregate doesn't support consuming update and delete changes which is produced by node Deduplicate(keep=[FirstRow], key=[order_id], order=[ROWTIME])`

We managed to get a simple example query reproducing this issue:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
  order_id STRING, 
  user_id STRING, 
  product STRING, 
  num BIGINT, 
  user_action_time TIMESTAMP(3), 
  WATERMARK FOR user_action_time AS user_action_time - INTERVAL '5' SECOND
) WITH ('connector' = 'datagen');

WITH Deduplicated AS (
  SELECT 
    order_id, 
    user_id, 
    product, 
    num, 
    user_action_time 
  FROM 
    (
      SELECT 
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
          PARTITION BY order_id 
          ORDER BY 
            user_action_time ASC
        ) AS row_num 
      FROM 
        Orders
    ) 
  WHERE 
    row_num = 1
) 
SELECT 
  user_id, 
  SUM(num) as num_sum 
FROM 
  TABLE(
    TUMBLE(
      TABLE Deduplicated, 
      DESCRIPTOR(user_action_time), 
      INTERVAL '5' MINUTES
    )
  ) 
GROUP BY 
  user_id, 
  window_start, 
  window_end
```

If the same query is run using `PROCTIME` instead of `ROWTIME`, the query runs successfully.

We are using flink 1.15.0

Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? I am not sure what the problem is.

```
WITH Deduplicated AS (
  SELECT 
    order_id, 
    user_id, 
    product, 
    num, 
    user_action_time 
  FROM 
    (
      SELECT 
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
          PARTITION BY order_id 
          ORDER BY 
            user_action_time ASC
        ) AS row_num 
      FROM 
        Orders
    ) 
  WHERE 
    row_num = 1
) 
SELECT 
  user_id, 
  SUM(num) as num_sum 
FROM Deduplicated
GROUP BY user_id, TUMBLE(user_action_time, INTERVAL '5' MINUTES);
```

Comment: That query definitely works, but it does not use [TVF](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/window-tvf/), it uses the old way of doing [windowed aggregations](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/window-agg/#group-window-aggregation) which seem to be deprecated

Comment: Probably, the append-only stream is supported with TVF.

Comment: Table `Orders` is an append-only stream table. I believe the issue is because the result of the Deduplication might be considered a non-append-only operation when using ROWTIME and watermarking?

Comment: `ORDER BY  user_action_time ASC` makes it updatable. It does not relate to watermarking, you can use many operations without updating and using watermark at the same time.

Comment: That makes sense. Is there any way to allow for this deduplication without making it updatable so that I can apply TVFs?

Comment: For more context, we only care to get one of the records with the same order_id, we don't really care which

Comment: I think you shouldn't (probably cannot) run away from updated streams, Flink relies on both types. If you want to create a complex stream application, you will eventually end up having an updated stream.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible. You can track https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-27539 (not sure yet if this is a bug or a new feature for Flink)